# Is there a Fourier invariant basis?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, invariance

There are some functions which are invariant under Fourier transformation up to scaling factors, eg. sech(pi*x), Gaussian function etc..
Is there a set of basis functions, which form an invariant basis set? (eg like sine cosine functions, not being invariant though) If you think that such a basis cannot exist, explain why this is so, or even better add a proof.

Comment: Does that mean you want to find an (orthonormal) basis $(f_i)$ with $\hat{f_i}=f_i$ for all $i$? Such a basis cannot exist.

Comment: If you have a basis whose elements are invariant under the Fourier transform, then the Fourier transform would be the identity operator. You almost get that. The set of normalized Hermite functions $\{ h_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ for which $\hat{h_{n}}=(i)^{n}h_{n}$. So $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ decomposes in 4 similar and orthogonal subspaces $H_{0}\oplus H_{1}\oplus H_{2}\oplus H_{3}$ where $\mathcal{F}=(i)^{n}I$ on $H_{n}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions

Comment: @TrialAndError that looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @TrialAndError To me too! I think your comment answers my question!

Comment: Good, glad I could help.

Comment: @TrialAndError Do you know about a fourier invariant/hermite function representation of spherical harmonics. Maybe one way to get there is just to use the hermite functions on the Riemann sphere. Not sure how and if that works. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of anything that will give you what you want.

Comment: @TrialAndError Legendre polynomials expanded in a hermitean polynomial basis? But I could not find anything in that direction. However I can't think of any reason, why this shouldn't be possible at least in principle.

Comment: @TrialAndError I posted this as a new question:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962172/how-does-a-fourier-invariant-representation-of-spherical-harmonics-look-like