# How does a fourier invariant representation of spherical harmonics look like?

Tags: fourier-transform, spherical-harmonics

The Hermite functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions are fourier invariant up to scaling. How does a fourier transform  invariant representation of spherical harmonics look like? The Laplace's spherical harmonics ${\displaystyle Y_{\ell }^{m}(\theta ,\varphi )}$ expanded in Hermite polynomials?

Comment: Maybe http://www.ams.org/proc/1996-124-05/S0002-9939-96.../S0002-9939-96-03189-9.pdf leads to an answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Example:_3D_isotropic_harmonic_oscillator   might also be useful.